# How to change orientation (degrees) using SimpleXlsxWriter C++ (programmatically in code)?

Tags: c++, xlsxwriter

How can I change orientation (degrees) using SimpleXlsxWriter C++ (programmatically in code)?

[image]

Comment: By reading the documentation or exploring their code. From what I see in the Log "Cell styles: fonts, fills, borders, alignment, multirow text" I don't see orientation. Maybe you can code the feature...

Comment: You can do this with [libxlsxwriter](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/format_8h.html#ae690004cd77f48646da07796b540c309). There is also a C++ wrapper for it [libxlsxwriterpp](https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/libxlsxwriterpp).